# How to add UITableView in a UIAlertView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertview

How do I dynamically add UITableView in UIAlertView. After adding subView of UIAlertView to UITableView it is not displayed.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.frame         =   CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 200);
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

@IBAction func textFieldCliked(sender: AnyObject) {
    alertView.message = "table view"
    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
    alertView.addSubview(tableView)
    alertView.show()
}
```

Comment: I have not added let alertView = UIAlertView() here..but i have added in my code..still its not working

Comment: You can't do this.Just for in your items and add buttons

Comment: Firstly, `UIAlertView` is deprecated as of iOS 8, so you probably should take a look at [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/). Secondly, Alerts aren't designed to contain custom subviews (like a TableView). Consider presenting your table in a modal as Alerts are designed to allow users to make a selection from some available actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can do that with `UIAlertView`, but you can make a small View and present it modally or something like `UIPopoverPresentationController`

Answer (score 3):

To create a UITableView in Swift:

1. Create a UITableViewController class.
2. Populate its delegates(no. of rows,didSelect,cellForRowAtIndexPath etc.) with necessary code.
3. Now call an instance of it in the `AlertViewController`.
4. Pass needed data to the TableView (like no. of rows and array of contents).
5. Add the TableView instance to your alert view.

my Code Snippet:

```
let alertController : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Select email ID", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
alertController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
alertController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0

let contactNumVC = contactNumberTableViewController ()

contactNumVC.count = emailIDs.count

contactNumVC.numbersArray = emailIDs

contactNumVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(alertController.view.frame.width, (44 * CGFloat(emailIDs.count)))

alertController.setValue(contactNumVC, forKeyPath: "contentViewController")
```

Answer (score 0):

To use alert type behaviour with table/image or custom button actions in several places of app, I have created a sample project Generic popover with all these examples. This is not using transition delegate.
This project also demo custom font and color to be adjusted to your app Theme.

create a custom tableview/imageview/buttons in storyboard and call as following

```
if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableContentViewController") as? TableContentViewController{
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
             vc.popOverDelegate = self
            self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
```

More information in the link
https://github.com/shruezee/GenericPopovers